# angular2 Material 2 Datepicker - Output Date Formats

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker in my angular4 project. How can I format selected date in input box with short format like "May 29, 2017". Currently it is displayed as 29/05/2017

Sample code:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput readonly="true" [mdDatepicker]="startDatePicker" [mdDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" class="date-text ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="startDatePicker" class="date-icon"></button>
</md-input-container>

<md-datepicker #startDatePicker [dateFormat]="'LL'" startView="month" [startAt]="currentDate"></md-datepicker>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('startDatePicker') startDatePicker: MdDatepicker<Date>;
```

PS. [dateFormat]="'LL'" is not working

Comment: Please post the code you have. There is a section at the link you posted for date formatting.

Comment: updated :) thank you

Comment: Can you please post solution?

Comment: I haven't found any solutions yet. :(

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set date format at the moment easily. There is no such property in Material 2 Datepicker [API](https://material.angular.io/components/component/datepicker) and the only proper way to change the format is to provide your own [DateAdapter](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/datetime/date-adapter.ts) implementation. The official documentation doesn't provide any instructions about that. There is only one basic [implementetion](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/datetime/native-date-adapter.ts) right now which defines formats according to the **locale**. There are many complains about that and more adapters should come soon. You can try to use one based on moment.js from [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/675#issuecomment-302275678) issue-thread or just wait.

You can also play with locales to get different formats in your Datepicker. But it's just a workaround till a proper official solution comes:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private dateAdapter:DateAdapter<Date>) {
    dateAdapter.setLocale('de'); // DD.MM.YYYY
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ill try to play around this Adapter

Comment: Excuse me, where could we get the location id like "de"?

Comment: @Einsamer, do you mean a [list](http://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php) of available locales?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think they should use `switch-case` somewhere

Comment: That works, but I tried to add it on the app module and it didn't work (I'm using a date picker in a sub-module)... That's annoying...

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use module providers for that:

```
@NgModule({
...
providers: [
     { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: navigator.language }
     ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

or you can replace *navigator.language* by *'de'* to achieve the same as above.